# Connected graph and longest paths

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple connected graph, and let P,Q be two longest paths in the graph. I need to prove that $P\bigcap Q \neq \emptyset$ (if you thinks of them as a set of vertices).

My attempt:
I tried assuming that $P\bigcap Q = \emptyset$ and try to get to a contradiction. Let P,Q be the paths $P = v_0v_1v_2...v_k$ , $Q = w_0w_1w_2...w_n$ ,($v_i$ and $w_i$ are vertices). Since G is a connected there is a path between $v_k$ and $w_0$. Then I look at the walk $v_0v_1v_2...v_kt_1t_2...t_pw_0w_1w_2...w_n$. Then I try to subtract all the circles in the walk since all the vertices that repeat have to be from $t_i$, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Use instead any path between $P$ and $Q$ not using vertices (except for the endpoints) of $P$ and $Q$.  The path $P$ has 2 parts, the path $Q$ has 2 parts.  Glue the longer parts, etc, etc.

Comment: Could you explain how to do it? I'm not sure I understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a path $R$ connecting some point in $P$ (call that point $a$) to some point in $Q$ (call that point $b$); its length is $\ge1$ because $P$ and $Q$ are disjoint.  We can assume none of the other points in $R$ are in $P$ or $Q$.  As you follow $R$ from $a$ to $b$ keep track of the most recent visit to $P$ with an auxiliary variable $\alpha$ which is initialized at $a$.  Stop at the first vertex $\beta\in Q$.  The portion of $R$ from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ will suffice for our purposes.  Hereafter pretend $(a,b)=(\alpha,\beta)$.

Now, $a$ divides $P$ into 2 portions: from $v_0$ to $a$ and from $a$ to $v_k$.  One of those parts is longer, with $\ge k/2$ steps (edges) in it.  Assume (by relabeling, if needed) that it is the part from $v_0$ to $a$.  Similarly, by relabeling if needed, the subpath of $Q$  from $b$ to $w_k$ has length $\ge k/2$. So your record-breaking new path goes along $P$ from $v_0$ to $a$ with $\ge k/2$ steps, from $a$ to $b$ along $R$ with $\ge 1$ step, and along $Q$ from $b$ to $w_k$.  Total length is $\ge k/2 + 1 + k/2 > k$.

Comment: How can you arrange a path from $a$ to $b$ that has no other points from $P$ or $Q$ for sure?

Comment: I am editing  my answer.

Comment: Now I understand. Nice answer by the way.